# Нужно что бы при изменении input number изменялось и значение input range

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я добавлю это кастомный реннж и его движение реализованно засчет background-size, мне нужно что бы это значение для ренжа можно было поменять с окошка справа(number), я не знаю как это сделать уже(
Вот ссылка на кодпен с моей проблемой,спасибо :3
https://codepen.io/maximyaroschuk/pen/vYppVOE

```
                    <input class="slider-range-counter" id="rangevalue" type="number" value="200" min="200" step="100" max="50000" oninput="range.value=value">

.slider-range,
.slider-range-counter {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.slider-range-counter {
  width: 85px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid $grey-400;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.slider-range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #e9ecef;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#367bf5, #367bf5);
  background-size: 2% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.slider-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background: url("../img/slider-dot.svg");
    cursor: grab;
  }
  .slider-range::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
  }

  .slider-range::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background: url("../img/slider-dot.svg");
    cursor: grab;
  }
  .slider-range::-moz-range-thumb:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
  }

  .slider-range::-ms-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background: url("../img/slider-dot.svg");
    cursor: grab;
  }
  .slider-range::-ms-thumb:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
  }
.slider-range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
.slider-range::-moz-range-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
.slider-range::-ms-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
  }
const rangeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]');

function handleInputChange(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  if (e.target.type !== "range") {
    target = document.getElementById("range");
  }
  const min = target.min;
  const max = target.max;
  const val = target.value;

  target.style.backgroundSize = ((val - min) * 100) / (max - min) + "% 100%";
}

rangeInputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", handleInputChange);
});
```

Comment: Переместите пожалуйста свой код сюда в Code Snippet

Comment: и замените scss на обычный css для воспроизведения

Comment: "я не знаю как это сделать уже" --- это не описание проблемы. напиши полностью что не получается, в чём сложность, что происходит или не происходит

Comment: У меня есть это ползунок, при изменении именно его все работает корректно, фон подтягивается и все выглядит отлично, но у меня еще есть задача сделать возможным изменение значения этого ползунка из второго инпута типа number, сейчас если менять из инпута number слайдер работает некорректно, значения не передаются, были попытки сделать это через .addEventListener change, но это не увенчалось успехом

Comment: Чёрт подери, всё думаю от чего вопрос такой знакомый?! Вы же вчера спрашивали об уже и вам @АлексейШиманский уже говорил как надо сделать. Вы не ответили на его совет, не показали (кодом) как попытались прислушаться к его совету, а вместо этого решили переформулировать свой вопрос и задать как новый. Вас могут и "покарать" модераторы за повторные вопросы :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский думаю один из вопросов стоит закрыть или отметить как дубликат. Просто не могу понять на каком из вопросов ставить тревогу) На том где вопрос не понятен, но уже был дан совет или там где вопрос чётко задан?))

Comment: Там где вопрос четко задан)

Comment: Я старый удалил, там неправильно была описана проблема

Comment: @МаксимЯрощук А данный вам совет сюда не перенесли)) и перенесите свой код в Code Snippet (нажав на Ctrl+M в редакторе)